# Checking for decreasing sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am using Paul's Notes on Calculus on math.lamar.edu. In it, the author states that $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i^2}$ is an increasing series. But then says that $\sum\frac{2}{n^2}$ is decreasing. From what I know, the p-series is decreasing. But is the author just wrong on the first series I have? See the links below. Or is the author stating that the number $a_n<a_{n+1}$?

[1st](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/IntegralTest.aspx)

[2nd](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/MoreSequences.aspx)

Comment: In your second link I did not see any summation sign $\sum$.

Comment: $\{\dfrac{1}{n^2}\}$ is a decreasing sequence, however, the sequence of partial sums $\{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{1}{k^2}\}$ is an increasing sequence

Comment: Oh. So it is saying the sum $a_n<a_{n+1}$?

Comment: There is no sum in the second case. It simply says that $2/n^2>2/(n+1)^2$.

Comment: Yeah... $S_n\lt S_{n+1}$ is less confusing

Comment: You also seem to be using sequence and series interchangeably which might be causing additional confusion. Take care of that.

Comment: The series you have consists of positive terms. what happens when you keep adding a bunch of positive terms?. The sequence of partial sums keeps increasing whereas the sequence {$a_n$} is decreasing .